# define sass version to install when installing compass

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, compass-sass

Is there a way to define the sass version to install when installing compass with `gem install compass` ?

Specifying -v would only specify the compass version and not the version of its dependencies..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install Sass first, using the `--version / -v` flag to specify the version you like. Then install compass afterward, using the `--minimal-deps` so that it does not also upgrade the Sass gem as a part of installing compass.

```
gem install sass --version VERSION
gem install compass --minimal-deps
```

Note that `--minimal-deps` will upgrade a dependency if the installed version does not meet the dependency requirements.